# Where would I be able to download/purchase stencilled background artwork?

Tags: icon, background, glyphs

What I mean by "stencilled" artwork is cartoonish glyphs for the background of a graphic, visible on [this app page for Things](http://culturedcode.com) or in the [background of this graphic](http://dribbble.com/shots/1278049-Calendars-5-Event-Dialog-GIF?list=searches&tag=readdle) the [Ember app page](https://realmacsoftware.com/ember) in the top banner.

More than willing to pay, just haven't come across something like this.

Comment: I'm not sure this is considered a style by itself or more of a collage. I'd risk saying those designers probably did those graphics themselves using icons. [Handrawn / Sketch icons](http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/icons%20sketch/filetype/illustrations/source/basic#1e36f592) as a search term could be a good start.

Comment: I just saw hand drawn icons on Shutterstock yesterday. Dreamstime and istockphoto also sell illustrations.

Comment: Marking as duplicate since the sites mentioned in the other question have all sorts of illustrations available for purchase :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are pictograms. More commonly known as icons. There are plenty of places to purchased pre-made icon sets that you can then arrange into a collage like that. There are many, many options. Just google "stock icons". A popular one these days is http://thenounproject.com/